# Delaying dictionary attacks in exim

Tags: email, exim

I have ongoing attacks against my exim server.
I'm trying to delay the attempts with the following acl

```
  deny    condition     = ${if and {\
                        {>{$rcpt_count}{10}}\
                        {<{$recipients_count}{${eval:$rcpt_count/2}}} }}
          delay         = 5s
          message       = Rejected for too many bad recipients
          logwrite      = REJECT [$sender_host_address]: bad recipient count high [${eval:$rcpt_count-$recipients_count}]
         .endif
```

That delays once after the first 10 attempts.

```
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <e9tao7oo9grjtb@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <poubelle@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <rsmaa759aqtywn6@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <s6wslt7zsdh2@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <tomcio@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <guigui@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <diebauersausulem@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <eremeev@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <irf14f21a11rkqd@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:34 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <cent@mydomain.com>: Unrouteable address
2023-09-10 12:14:39 REJECT [212.164.218.15]: bad recipient count high [11]
2023-09-10 12:14:39 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <burhan@mydomain.com>: Rejected for too many bad recipients
2023-09-10 12:14:39 REJECT [212.164.218.15]: bad recipient count high [12]
2023-09-10 12:14:39 H=([212.164.218.15]) [212.164.218.15] F=<cxgbuwwat92dkvf@blagodom.net> rejected RCPT <alecs@mydomain.com>: Rejected for too many bad recipients
```

I want it to instead delay each subsequent attempt. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: you can possibly use a ratelimit, but it is somewhat unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: So put the maximum acceptable number into EOM-stage ACL, and the delay into RCPT TO-stage acl? I suspect your question is unclear because your configuration excerpt does not show the context you are using the rule in.

Comment: The spammer gets 10 attempts to send mail (all at 12:14:34) then he gets rejected with a five second delay. (to 12:14:39) then he gets to try many, many more times without the delay happening again  (typically 100 attempts, sometimes  200).  I want the remaining 90 attempts to be subject to a 5 second delay each. This all happens in acl_check_rcpt.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue/question, and did some research and testing.

The first thing you need to know is that SMTP was originally strictly command-response based, which means the client can send exactly one command to the server and has to wait for the response before it can send the next. Because that back-and-forth involves quiet a bit of waiting every time and thus creates latency, [RFC 2920](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2920) later introduced "SMTP Pipelining". This allows a client to send multiple commands in one batch to the server, which processes them and sends back the responses. In exim the availability of "SMTP Pipelining" can be controlled by the `pipelining_advertise_hosts` option, which by default allows it for everyone. I assume this is also the case for your configuration.

What I think happened in your case is that the client (aka spammer) connected to your exim server, was told it supports "SMTP Pipelining", and so it send a batch of 100 `RCPT TO:` commands. Your server received them and started to process them, running though the `acl_smtp_rcpt` acl for each recipient. The first 10 commands returned a `550 Unrouteable address` response each, with `550` being a [RFC5321 error code](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-4.2.3) meaning `Requested action not taken` followed by a human-readable reason. That reason can be set in exim with the `message` directive, and is also printed in the log after the colon. The client probably just ignored them; it is looking for valid recipients after all.

When processing the 11th command/recipient, the condition of your `deny` rule evaluated to true, and exim delays (sleeps) for 5 seconds; this is the one delay you see. After that it sends the `550 Rejected for too many bad recipients` response to the client. Because of the included (well known) reason, the client detects it crossed the line and there is no chance to find a valid recipient anymore; all following commands will be rejected too. Since there is nothing worthwhile to expect/gain anymore, it terminates the connection without waiting for the rest of the responses (and probably turns immediately to its next victim). While your server notices this (because TCP is used), it still continues to process the command batch. But because the SMTP connection to the client is already terminated, there is no point in delaying anymore; the only one it would delay is itself. So the delay is ignored and your server runs through the commands until the whole batch is done.

If the client would not terminate the connection, this would work like you expected it to: The 5s delay would be applied for each recipient after the 10th.

Assuming that the above is correct, the best solution I could come up with is to remove the default reason/message. If the server simply continues to respond with something like `550 Unrouteable address`, the client has no way to know it crossed the line and can't bail. Depending on how the client works, it may be enough to change/rephrase it to something different from the default so it is not handled specially.

Alternatively you can disable "SMTP Pipelining" in your server using the above mentioned option. The client will probably still abort after seeing the 11th answer with the telltale reason, and your server still only delays once, but at least you don't get the other 89 failed recipients in your log. The obvious downside is you "slow down" every client, but this can be somwhat elevated by enabling "SMTP Pipelining" only for selected "known good" clients.

And just as a side note: The delay doesn't have to be a static value, it can also be an expression. This makes it possible to implement progressive delays, where each additional invalid recipient will make it longer. The excellent [Spam Filtering for Mail Exchangers](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Spam-Filtering-for-MX/exim-smtpdelays.html) HowTo has an example of this.